# trying to install openCMS in windows with Tomcat its shows a 404 error

Tags: java, tomcat, opencms

i tried to install the openCMS in my local system . after doing all the steps in the manual i got the 404 error . i tried from CMD to run the setup it shows E:\Tomcat5\webapps\opencms\WEB-INF>setup
The input line is too long.
The syntax of the command is incorrect. can any one help me with this

Answer (score 0):

You are not supposed to run the setup from command line. You need to deploy the opencms.war into Tomcat's webapps folder, then start Tomcat, then you can run the setup via browser:

```
http://localhosthost:8080/opencms/setup/
```

See http://www.opencms.org/en/development/installation/server.html

Comment: hi , i did all that steps before only . that's y i mentioned in my question that i did all the step in the manual. its not working that's why i tries the command line. any one help me